# Type 'HTMLCollection' can only be iterated through when using the '--downlevelIteration' flag or with a '--target' of 'es2015' or higher

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, eslint

I am trying to create a loader for my static grid. I am using the `react-shimmer-skeleton` package source code while eslint is in strict mode. Here is the [link](https://github.com/FilipePfluck/react-shimmer-skeleton/blob/main/src/Components/Skeleton.tsx) for the respective repository file. It keeps throwing the error `TS2802: Type 'HTMLCollection' can only be iterated through when using the '--downlevelIteration' flag or with a '--target' of 'es2015' or higher`.

```
{element.children
  ? [...element.children]
      .map(child => renderElement(child as HTMLElement))
                    : null
}
```

I was able to resolve the other errors which were thrown by eslint using IntelliJ IDEA. But for this error, it is not having any quick fixes. Is there anything that I can do to fix this error without creating this `"downlevelIteration": true`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think creating `"downlevelIteration": true` is the most easy and viable option here.